# How to get details of email Account configured in iPhone/iPad

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios5

Hi I am making and iPad application. I need to authenticate user if he configured his email account in device and get his email and other available details. Can you guys please help me with this.

And also email is not configure I want to redirect him to the mail settings. So far I got following code for the same

```
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"mailto:"]];
```

Please help me guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NO You can never get USER DETAILS configured in mail app, It breaks user privacy and hence not allowed

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to get the details of account. And, it's against the policy of Apple. If you do this in your app, then apple can reject your app. However, using below code you can check at least one email account is enabled on the device :

```
Class mailClass = (NSClassFromString(@"MFMailComposeViewController"));
if ([mailClass canSendMail])
{
    //There is email account configured
}
else
{
    //Email account is not configured. Can't send the email.
}
```

Comment: Thanks Rushi I know this But I need to get users details

Comment: @ShashankKulshrestha : hey there's not way you can get it. It's against the data security policy of apple. You might get some third party API's but I'd suggest not to go for this.